# How to insert php value into html tag by $_GET['NameField']

Tags: php, get, tags

i want to fill value into html tag bij php Url post
The orignalcode is

```
<div class="addevent" data-event='{
                            "title":"Appointment titel", 
                            "start":"2020/01/25 10:00", 
                            "end":"2020/01/25 12:00", 
                            "desc":"Description of appointment",
                            "location":"somewhere"
                            }'>
```

I tried this:

```
"title":<?php $_GET['titel']?>,
```

i received the values bij url post
`<?php $_GET['titel']?>`
`<?php $_GET['start']?>`
 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PHP array with all the values, and use `json_encode()` to convert it to JSON for the `data-event` attribute.

```
$event = json_encode(['title' => $_GET['titel'], 'start' => $_GET['start'], ...]);
?>
<div class="addevent" data-event='<?php echo htmlentities($event); ?>'
```